# How can we represent a quaternion multiplication by quadrance and spread?

Tags: trigonometry, quaternions, division-algebras

I don't speak well English, so please edit this question to be more accurate.

Quaternions are considered as the quotient of the 3D vectors division.

$${\bf v}\,{\bf r}^{-1}=-\frac{{\bf v}\,{\bf r}}{r^2}=-\frac{1}{r^2}(-{\bf v}\cdot{\bf r}+{\bf v}\times{\bf r})$$

but in its definition we have dot product and cross product that depends on the angle between the vectors.

To make quaternions more rational, I would like to apply [rational trigonometry's concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry), *quadrance* and *spread*, to avoid using transcendental functions sine and cosine.

So, can we implement a quaternion/division-algebra by applying quadrance and spread instead of magnitude and angle?

Comment: The dot product and cross product can be defined using coordinates relative to an orthonormal basis. They do **not** depend on using angles and trig functions. That is just one common alternative way of computing them.

Comment: @Somos You are right but let's assume we don't want to use a basis.

Comment: And so you think that rational trigonometry does **not** also use coordinates relative to a basis?

Comment: @Somos it does not use coordinates relative to a basis.  Vectors are independent of basis despite being represented by them. We manually define the orientation of a cross product (right hand rule) that if we apply rational trigonometry we get rid of it, so the answer to this question is very important.

Comment: You are using $r$ to denote both a vector and a scalar - please don't do that. And keep in mind quaternion division, like multiplication, is noncommutative, so you can't in general write a "fraction" of two vectors. What is true is that if $\bf v$ and $\bf r$ are vectors and $r=\|{\bf r}\|$ then $$ {\bf v}\,{\bf r}^{-1}=-\frac{{\bf v}\,{\bf r}}{r^2}=-\frac{1}{r^2}(-{\bf v}\cdot{\bf r}+{\bf v}\times{\bf r}). $$ Anyway, if someone asked you if you can implement *complex numbers* (and how they model 2D rotations) with quadrance and spread, what would you say?

Comment: @runway44 Thanks. You are right we can also ask this question for 2D rotations.